# Is the amount of bytes in a Unicode character always 1-4, or can it be a different length?

Tags: encryption, unicode, cryptography

So I came across a problem where someone had encoded some text into Unicode, but added a number to the end of each Unicode character to make the message more secure. The problem is, when I try to decode it I can't figure out which number I need to remove because the length of each Unicode character can vary in length.

Does anyone know the what the most common length for a Unicode character is? Please try to answer as simply as possible because I'm not accustomed to using Unicode in encryption.

Comment: See [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Unicode is not a byte encoding.  [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), [ISO-8859-1/Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), etc, those are byte encodings. How a given Unicode codepoint (which is just a number assigned to a character/glyph) maps to a byte sequence depends on the particular encoding used. UTF-8 uses 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes, depending on codepoint value. UTF-16 uses 2 or 4 bytes, depending on codepoint value. Latin-1 uses 1 byte only. There is no "common length for a Unicode character".

Answer (score 4):

If your Unicode is 1 to 4 bytes, then I assume you are using UTF-8 encoding; it is certainly common.

UTF-8 code points can be 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes long, with distinct patterns to the bytes to help you recognise them.

- 1 byte: 0xxxxxxx
- 2 byte: 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
- 3 byte: 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
- 4 byte: 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx

The leading bits of each byte tell you what it is, whether a leading byte or a following byte.  Leading bytes also tell you how many following bytes to expect.

So if you find a byte: 11010110 you know it is the leading byte of a two-byte code point.  You expect to see one following byte: 10xxxxxx after it, followed by the leading byte of the next code point.